# Name for a single partition of URL path

Tags: url, terminology

Suppose we have this URL:

```
https://superuser.com/questions/ask
```

This is its path: `/questions/ask`

What is the name for a partition of a path, i.e. `/questions`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) section 3.3, "Path", `questions` and `ask` are **segments**. The slash itself is not part of the segment but is used as a separator before and between segments.